# Why does a AC condenser tend to freeze up when the refrigerant is low?

Tags: thermodynamics

Looking at the P-H diagram, the working fluid pressure drops when it goes through the expansion valve. Temperature drops at constant enthalpy due to Joule-Thompson effect. Therefore the system must be pushing the working fluid to lower pressures when there is not enough refrigerant, but why would it do that? Is the suction pump working harder?

Comment: What controls the pressure in the region after the expansion valve?

Comment: I'd guess the combination of the expansion valve throttle (can it be throttled?) and the suction pump?

Comment: There must be some sort of control system which senses the pressure and controls the speed of the pump.